# Remove a particular column data in SQL without deleting entire row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server, where one column contains excel files.

Now we need to remove those excel files only without deleting the entire row. because the size of this table is increasing day by day, we need to 
    remove old data to decrease the size of this table

```
Id      file_name  Code
1001    abc.xlsx   A1
1002    das.xlsx   A2
1003    kap.xlsl   A3
```

I have done the below

```
Update rec_table 
 set file_name = Null where id = '1001'
```

Will this help to reduce the size of the table?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will reduce the size of table...the reason behind is that ....

your column datatype is Suppose ( `VARBINARY(MAX)` ) then ...then you are updating the column as `NULL`...
so the size of `Table` get Reduce...

Comment: Does saving 8 bytes matter?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server the size of a Table is calculated by adding the Sie of every row in the table. Ie if a Table is having 10 rows, then the Total size of the table would be the sum of the total size of the 10 rows.

For a Row, the Total size is calculated by calculating the size of every column.

For Example in your case, the Size of the row with ID 1001 will be the

> Size of the value in Column ID + Size Of Value in Column File_Name + Size of Value in COlumn Code

so if a Column Holds the value `NULL` for a Particular Row, then that COlumn will have a Data size of 0

updating the values to NULL for a particular column will reduce the size of the column, But how much it gets reduced will depend on the Type of the Column and Data stored in it

Which means, *If your Column File_name holds a Data of 100 bytes for Row id 1001, then updating the Value to `NULL` will reduce the Table size by 100 Bytes*

You may use the following queries to find out the table / Row Size

**For getting the Size and Details for the whole table**

```
dbcc showcontig ('Person.Person') with tableresults
```

**To Get the Data Size of a Particular column for each Row in the Database**

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(FirstName) FROM Person.Person
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this reduce the size of the table?  Probably.

Will this release free space to the database?  Probably not -- until you compact the database.

Is this an expensive operation?  Very.

Databases store tables on *data pages*.  Each data page contains one or more rows.  If you have wide columns, then these might be stored on their own data pages.

The number of rows that fit on a page depends on the size of the rows.  A page is about 8k bytes.  If a row is 100 bytes, then a table with 1 row occupies the same space as one with 50 rows.

When you remove a column from a table, the entire table needs to be rewritten.  *This is a very expensive operation.*  And it might take a long time.  Often it is faster to select the columns that you do want and reload the original table.

Removing a column is -- to me -- a very curious way to reduce the size of a table.  More typically, older data would be removed.  The most efficient method is to partition the table by time, using whatever the appropriate date/time column might be.  Then you can quickly recover space by dropping a partition.

Comment: The size of the table is 90 GB, i need to reduce the size of this table. will partition help to achieve this

Comment: @user2922926 . . . I think I would focus on removing rows and partitioning the table before removing columns.  You will need temp space for almost any operation you attempt.